# Words whose plural has a plural

Tags: irregular-plurals, inflections

I'm working on an app that works with inflections and realized "person" has three levels of plurality:

person -> people -> peoples

Are there any other words in English that act this way?

Comment: I think you should remove "person" from the question. And focus on "people" being plural, and then "peoples" also being plural, because "people" definitely have two definitions (1) a single collection of persons, (2) the plural counter for "person".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Peoples* is not the plural of *the plural of person*, it is the plural of the singular *people*. A people is a group of persons with a shared heritage, association, or trait.

> The Dominicans are a proud people.

It just happens that a related meaning of *people* is as the plural of *person*, especially when referring to persons who have some identity as a group.

One similar case are for names of animals which serve as their own plurals--*fish*, *sheep*, etc. Pluralizing these can be correct, but mostly when referring to multiple categories.

> My favorite fishes are the betta and the clownfish.

Answer (score 1):

Spaghetto, spaghetti, spaghettis.

[Spaghetto,](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/spaghetto#English): A single strand of spaghetti.

[Spaghettis](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/spaghetti#English): the plural of *spaghetti*. One usage is "spaghetti Western". Another is "spaghetti recipe", as in

> This is one of the best spaghettis I have ever had.

EDIT: As Mike points out in the comments,

Panino, panini, paninis,

is a better example.

Comment: *Panini* might be a somewhat stronger example, as I'd venture that the singular *panino* is more familiar than *spaghetto*.

Comment: @Mike: you're right ... *panini* is much better.